# app.delete raise syntax error on express with nodeclipse IDE

Tags: node.js, express, syntax-error, nodeclipse

does anyone familiar with this error on nodeclipse IDE ?

```
  app.delete('/delete', function(req, res) {
  ....
  });
```

**Syntax error on token ".", , expected**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete` is a reserved word in JavaScript. In `express`, you should use `app.del(...)`. For you example, the following code should work:

```
app.del('/delete', function(req, res) {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! much more elegant :)

Comment: @AviramNetanel FYI, in express 4.x, `app.del(...)` is deprecated. It is been replaced with `app.delete(...)`. I don't know wether Nodeclipse IDE will recognise this change.

Comment: they should just continue supporting del... it is shorter IMO. Vim also highlights delete as a reserved word.

Comment: @Geoyws Yes, but it's quite intuitive. VIM syntax colour for Javascript should be updated to handle this situation.

Answer (score 6):

try

```
 app['delete'](...)
```

delete is a reserved word in old ES versions,so unless nodeclipse supported ES5 it may raise an error.

If nodeclipse works with jslint ,write at the top of your file

```
/*jslint es5:true*/
```

and it should remove the error.

Answer (score 2):

`delete` was reserved word before EcmaScript 5.

Nodeclipse by default uses Eclipse JSDT-based Editor, that is not EcmaScript 5 aware (but JSHint integration is)

This is issue [#70](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/70).